# Conda Specify channel for package Installed Offline

Tags: conda

I manually download the `tar.bz2` files from a channel and `conda install` the local packages. As a result, the channel of the packages in the conda list turned out to be **unknown**. This cause me some trouble because when I install other packages dependent on the installed ones with online `conda install`, conda donnot know where the packages are actually downloaded from, and tend to `upgrade` the package from **unknown** source, which means that conda download the same package that I just downloaded again.

How can I let conda know the package is from the channel from which I downloaded. Or is there a way to let conda do with the package from the **unknown** channel which I just installed?

So many thanks!

Comment: having this issue also